# Generate Beep in microseconds c#

Tags: c#, audio, beep

I want to generate a rectangular beep in microseconds (100 microseconds), but c# only provides me it in miliseconds (1 or more).
Here is an image of what I want to do:
Image - Rectangular pulse in microseconds

[image]

What can I do?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: I had no idea that c# draws rectangles based on time explicitly.. Could you please clarify and show some code?

Comment: Easy enough to do with the [NAudio library](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2009/10/playback-of-sine-wave-in-naudio.html).  Do keep the physics in mind, time resolution is limited to the sample rate.  Which doesn't matter, nobody has ears good enough to hear the difference.  Or to hear this signal at all btw.

Comment: That kind of usage is indicative of communication protocols. For that, you do need a precise resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using DirectX.Sound?
https://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/Generating-Sound-Waves-with-C-Wave-Oscillators

With DirectX, you can create your own waveforms however with the sample frequency of 44.1KHz (<strike>0.22mS</strike>  0.02267mS or 22.67uS) it doesn't look like you be able to do a precisely what you need but you could get close.  The nearest pulse width you'll get to match requirement is 90.7 uS or 113.4 uS.

Comment: A single sample at 44.1kHz is .023us.  It doesn't really matter though. In a millisecond you can get a single cycle of a 1kHz sine at any sample rate greater than 2kHz.

Comment: @jaket  Actually, we're both wrong! - the duration is 0.022mS (22 uS) i.e 1/44100   I'll edit my answer to correct this.